# What is the maximum number of cabin crew members on an A320 load sheet?

Tags: airbus-a320, weight-and-balance, crew

What is the maximum allowable number of cabin crew members to be mentioned on the load sheet for A320, with respect to weight and balance? And does the number of deadheading crew members add to this figure ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there are six crew seats in the A320 cabin. as long as the operating crew occupies these seats they will be included the crew figures for loadsheet purposes. In the event that these seats are occupied by non-crew they will need to be included manually. Not really common nowadays but it was routinely done in the 90s.

In the event that there is crew occupying a passenger seat (deadheading) they will be trimmed as a passenger.

The reason is most loadsheet programmes will adjust the Dry Operating Index  (and dry operating weight) depending on the number of crews entered in the crew field (eg 3/5). If a crew (deadheading or otherwise) is occupying a passenger seat, the system will only be able to account for this person if he is checked in.

Depending on the airline and the local country regulations it may not be possible for deadheading crews to travel on the General Declaration, instead they may be required to have tickets and be included in the passenger manifest.

To summarise, everything on the airplane must be accounted for, both in terms f weight as well as its effect on the trim, irrespective of whether it is a person on a jumpseat or passenger seat.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it really helps, but my point is it acceptable to add dead head crew to the active crew with a number above the available jump seat ?  Ex A 320 has 6 jump seats, is it possible for crew to be  2/10 ?

Comment: Hi Hossam, The various crew configurations available in the load-sheet system will only cater to the max number of crew seats available. You would only be able to select a combination from 2/0 to 4/6 (assuming only 6 crew seats available) as the technical services dept have only calculated the affect on the weight and trim in these seats.